# Superhero kid-trio TV series

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember that there's three kids that I think might be superheroes of some sort? They have a butler and they are crime stoppers.

There was one episode where a kid was committing crimes, having used an age-accelerating ray to make himself older in order to commit the crimes. The youngest of the three kids was struck with said ray at some point and gradually got older throughout the episode because of it.

I believe there was another episode where this card game was released and if someone happened to touch a card from one of the cursed decks, they would transform into the creature that was on the card; which, again, I believe the youngest of the kids went through a transformation from directly being affected, in this case, by the card. This has been bugging me for a few days.

It was a kids' show, maybe from the 2000s to early 2010s, if not earlier.

Comment: [Zevo-3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMwAVvmLQ08)?

Comment: [Teamo-Supremo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOCr_UC3qxM)?

Comment: No, neither of those seem quite right... It was a semi-realistic western style, somewhat like Zevo-3 but they were three siblings, I believe Caucasian.

Comment: You should edit that into the question. You might also want to have a read through [How to ask a good story-ID question?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see if the checklists jog free any extra memories.